# Authenticated cross-origin XHR with qooxdoo

Tags: javascript, cors, qooxdoo

qooxdoo's qx.data.store.Json, when used for cross-origin requests, won't send any cookies or authentication data.

This requirement is not as uncommon as it may seem. Imagine a typical developer's setup: a JavaEE backend running on localhost:8080, and qooxdoo application served by "source-server" generator task or IDE's built-in web server at, say, localhost:8181.

After successful authentication, a JSESSIONID cookie will be set for localhost. For XHR (localhost:8181 -> localhost:8080) to succeed, this cookie should be sent along with the request.

It's clear that the cookie is not sent due to lack of support for withCredentials property in qx.bom.request.Xhr, and maybe it deserves a separate RFE. What I'm looking for is quick-and-dirty workaround to get development process up and running. What's the best way to do it? Can it be done without patching framework code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to get dirty ;-) Constructor of [`qx.data.store.Json`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.5.1/apiviewer/#qx.data.store.Json) accepts delegate, [`qx.data.store.IStoreDelegate`](http://demo.qooxdoo.org/3.5.1/apiviewer/#qx.data.store.IStoreDelegate), which has `configureRequest` method.

```
var delegate = {'configureRequest': function(request)
{
  // request is `qx.io.request.Xhr`
  // request.getTransport() is `qx.bom.request.Xhr`
  var nativeXhr = request.getTransport().getRequest();
  nativeXhr.withCredentials = true;
}};
var store = new qx.data.store.Json('http://localhost/your.json', delegate);
```

Besides, `qx.data.store.Json` is just 135 SLOC. It shouldn't be hard to write your own store.

Comment: Oh wow, works like a charm. I'm lucky to have only a couple of qx.data.store.Json invocations in my app, but if there were dozens, it would have lead to massive refactoring (to use self-written store, for example). It would be good to have an ability to turn `withCredentials` on for the whole application (or URL pattern). @saaj, do you think this is worth including to mainstream? I address the same question to qooxdoo authors in case they stumble upon this topic.

Comment: @MartinSchmidt I think `configureRequest` in the delegate is exactly the means of configuration for a specific case, like yours. If you had many occurrences of the store, it would make sense to subclass `qx.data.store.Json` and pass the delegate to the parent constructor. I usually subclass Qooxdoo IO classes in my projects, to make them more convenient, like with [RPC](http://code.google.com/p/cherrypy-webapp-skeleton/source/browse/trunk/frontend/source/class/webapp/network/Rpc.js). I don't think here's a room for improvement, except adding `withCredentials` property to `qx.io.request.Xhr`.